# How to change the form controls id and name in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, razorengine, razor-pages

I have a contact Razor page backed by a ViewModel called `ContactViewModel`. The html generated is below.

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text" id="ContactViewModel_FirstName" name="ContactViewModel.FirstName" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text" id="ContactViewModel_LastName" name="ContactViewModel.LastName" value="" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

I have another Razor Page with a form backed by `ShippingAddressViewModel`.

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text" id="ShippingAddressViewModel_FirstName" name="ShippingAddressViewModel.FirstName" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text" id="ShippingAddressViewModel_LastName" name="ShippingAddressViewModel.LastName" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control" type="text" id="ShippingAddressViewModel_ZipCode" name="ShippingAddressViewModel.ZipCode" value="" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

I want to apply JS client validation to the `FirstName` and `LastName`. Since the `name` and `id` of the controls are different, I have to create two JavaScript methods to target the controls.

Is there a way in Razor Pages to back the page with different view models but the `id` and `name` are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused because you have an object. You can create two different variables in your PageModel.

```
[BindProperty]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Now you your view can have the following code:

```
<input asp-for="FirstName" />
<input asp-for="LastName" />
```

This will have as a result to have the following html:

```
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="" />
<input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" value="" />
```

I hope it helps.